# How to map null values in Elastic Search?

Tags: json, elasticsearch, mapping

I am trying add the following json doc to a new index:

```
[
        {
          "name": "C$",
          "caption": "Default share",
          "description": "Default share",
          "install_date": null,
          "status": "OK",
          "maximum_allowed": null,
          "allow_maximum": true,
          "path": "C:\\",
          "share_type": 2147483648,
          "access_mask": 0
        },
        {
          "name": "D$",
          "caption": "Default share",
          "description": "Default share",
          "install_date": null,
          "status": "OK",
          "maximum_allowed": null,
          "allow_maximum": true,
          "path": "D:\\",
          "share_type": 2147483648,
          "access_mask": 0
        },
        {
          "name": "temp",
          "caption": "temp",
          "description": "",
          "install_date": null,
          "status": "OK",
          "maximum_allowed": 5,
          "allow_maximum": false,
          "path": "C:\\temp",
          "share_type": 0,
          "access_mask": 2032127
        }
      ]
```

As you can see, the `install_date` is null and the `maximum_allowed` field can be a number or null type.

I have been experimenting with the following schema doc:

```
                            "share": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "name": {
                                        "type": "text"
                                    },
                                    "caption": {
                                        "type": "text"
                                    },
                                    "description": {
                                        "type": "text"
                                    },
                                    "install_date": {
                                        "type": "date",
                                        "fields": {
                                            "keyword": {
                                                "type": "keyword",
                                                "null_value": "NULL"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "status": {
                                        "type": "text"
                                    },
                                    "allow_maximum": {
                                        "type": "boolean"
                                    },
                                    "maximum_allowed": {
                                        "type": "long",
                                        "fields": {
                                            "keyword": {
                                                "type": "keyword",
                                                "null_value": "NULL"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "path": {
                                        "type": "text"
                                    },
                                    "share_type": {
                                        "type": "long"
                                    },
                                    "access_mask": {
                                        "type": "long"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

I drop and recreate the index a fresh each time, i test out my code changes.
Each time, ES just ignores any field that has a NULL value assigned to it.

*(If it helps to clarify, I am inserting documents using the NEST SDk and dotnet 7.)*

What is the correct approach to handling null-able values with ES.

Answer (score 0):

###### The `null_value` needs to be the same data type as the field. For instance, a long field cannot have a string null_value.

```
PUT null_value?pretty
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "maximum_allowed": {
        "type": "long",
        "null_value": -1
      },
      "install_date": {
        "type": "date",
        "null_value": -1
      },
      "some_keyword": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "null_value": "NULL"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
PUT null_value/_doc/1?pretty
{
  "maximum_allowed": null
}
```

---

```
PUT null_value/_doc/2?pretty
{
  "maximum_allowed": []
}
```

---

```
PUT null_value/_doc/3?pretty
{
  "maximum_allowed": 1
}
```

---

```
GET null_value/_search?pretty
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "maximum_allowed": "-1"
    }
  }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/null-value.html

[image]

Comment: I have tried this already, hence why i threw the kitchen sink at it. I will give it another guy.
The only way i got it working was throught dev kibana console rest api. If i go through postman via an internal api using the NEST SDK the NULLs get truncated. Regardless I will try again.

Comment: please let me know the result

Comment: I managed to fix my issue it was a combination of c# code changes and schema changes to get it work correctly. I will post up an answer tomorrow.

Comment: thanks for your feedback and happy to hear it fixed